# PDO and For Each Loop: Incorrect variable being output

Tags: php, variables, loops, foreach, pdo

So I have a few for each loops, and I'm trying to echo out the value of $sql at the very end. I'm actually using it with PDO but the echo demonstrates the issue.

```
$values = "1,2";
$values = explode(',',$values);

$set1 = "2,4";
$set1 = explode(',',$set1);
$set2 = "3,2";
$set2 = explode(',',$set2);

foreach($set1 as $set1val){
  if ($set1val==2) {
    $sql = "sql one runs";//should run on 1st iteration since 2 will equal 2
    echo 'hi';//should echo on 1st iteration since 2 will equal 2
  }
}

foreach($set2 as $set2val){
  if ($set2val==2) {
    $sql = "sql two runs";//should run on 2nd iteration since 2 will equal 2
    echo 'bye';//should echo on 2nd iteration since 2 will equal 2
  }
}

foreach($values as $value){
  echo $sql;
  $stmt = $db->query($sql);
}

//The Result Output
'hi'  'bye'  'sql two runs'  'sql two runs' <-- doesn't echo 'sql one runs' 

//The Output Required
'hi'  'bye'  'sql one runs'  'sql two runs' <-- Works great, but not outputting this
```

How can I make it output the output required? Any idea how to do this so the correct statement is echoed/runs?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Looping through an array just to do something for a single value is a nonsense pattern. Also, are you trying to... dynamically decide which query run? Or what exactly is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @deceze I think I was complicating something more than I should have. I was trying to dynamically decide which query to run using the same variable name, hoping it would take into consideration the order the $sql variables were 'activated' and execute them in that order, instead of overwriting the previous run of it and running the same query twice. Does that make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It never echos `sql one runs` because the second `foreach` overwrites it with `sql two runs`. If you need to save the sql strings through the end of the script, you could store them in an array. It's difficult to specify how as it's not clear how `$values` is  related to the SQL, i.e., which SQL should run with which `$value`.

Comment: Thanks webbiedave, I already know what the issue is, I'm trying to find a solution

Comment: I did. I added `store them in an array`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you first save `sql one runs` in `$sql`, but the next thing you do with `$sql` is saving `sql two runs`, overwriting the previous value. So you need to save those values in an array, and modify the last `foreach`. Something like this:

```
foreach($set1 as $set1val){
  if ($set1val==2) {
    $sql[0] = "sql one runs";//should run on 1st iteration since 2 will equal 2
    echo 'hi';//should echo on 1st iteration since 2 will equal 2
  }
}

foreach($set2 as $set2val){
  if ($set2val==2) {
    $sql[1] = "sql two runs";//should run on 2nd iteration since 2 will equal 2
    echo 'bye';//should echo on 2nd iteration since 2 will equal 2
  }
}

foreach($sql as $value){
  echo $value;
  $stmt = $db->query($value);
}
```